# Why is Azure ServiceBus explorer showing loads of old messages when creating IoT Hub Listener

Tags: azure, azure-eventhub, azure-iot-hub

During investigations on why IoT Hub is responding very slowly and sometimes throwing Internal Server Errors on D2C messages i was coming across ServiceBus explorer (https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer) to monitor messages received by IoT Hub.

After creating an IoT Hub Listener and starting monitoring events i was quite surprised by the result. I saw loads of old messages (even a couple of month old ones). I configured IoT Hub Message retention to the default of 1 day, so i was expecting messages older than 1 day to be dismissed automatically.

Do you have an idea where these messages come from? Where are they persisted and how can i get rid of them?

Thank you very much for your help!
Best regards
Markus

Comment: The message retention policy defines the *minimum* days the messages are kept.

Comment: Thank you for that hint, @PeterBons. Are the messages persisted internally in IoT Hub  / Event Hub ? As far as i understand the linked blog post i just don't have to care about that old messages as the cleanup is managed internally by IoT Hub / Event Hub ?

Comment: @MarkusS. Have a look at the feature of the Event Hubs - checkpointing https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/event-hubs-features#event-consumers Note, that using the IoT Hub Routes, the messages are routed directly to the custom endpoint, for instance, to the Service Bus Queue.

Comment: Correct, you do not have to care about, or clean/remove, the old messages.